# Sorting list having itemBean by date?

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, comparator

how to sort a list by date in android

```
List<ItemBean> listIB = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
for(int i=0; i<DispLibActivity.itemListVect.size(); i++)
{
    listIB.add(DispLibActivity.itemListVect.get(i));
}
```

ItemBean class have a member date

```
public class ItemBean implements Parcelable{
    String item_id, item_title, image_url, link_url, description, publish_date,
        in_app_date, sub_section_id, type, duration, orig_url, sync;
    ....
    ....
}
```

I want to sort list "listIB" with its member "publish_date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the date string, get the `Date` object and confront the time in milliseconds in a comparator.

Comment: i uderstand SimpleDateFormat; but cannot get the milliseconds comparision. Well i got the answer, so thanks "blackbelt"

Comment: use parse to get the date http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29 , the you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29 or http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29 in a comparator with Collections.sort(...)